# Lots of retries and transaction expired on NEAR localnet

Tags: nearprotocol

We created a test chain that runs locally on a computer, launches a chain with 4 validators (quite similar to `localnet`) and from there, we are deploying a smart contract testing various aspect of the chain (failed transactions, async receipts, args encoding, logs, and such stuff).

Everything can be run/seen here https://github.com/streamingfast/battlefield-near (it’s a bunch of scripts that facilitate running this network and the transactions).

When I deploy my contract, it always requires like 2 to 3 retries before getting the transaction to pass correctly. More than that, I would say in 33% of the cases, I reach the retry limit and get a `Transaction Expired` error.

This seems weird to me that such amount of retry is required to deploy a contract assuming that everything runs locally on my computer. When deploying the contract, it’s the only transaction going in, so there should be no congestion involved (there should be actually no traffic at all).

How the contract deployment can pass right away without retries and without never expiring the transaction?

Answer (score 3):

It is possible that the network is too fast given that, as you mentioned, it is a one-node local network. This may cause the transaction to expire quickly, especially given that the default value for expiration on localnet is quite small I believe. Check for `transaction_validity_period` in your genesis.json and see if setting it to a large number helps.

Comment: It's a 4 node network not a one-node network. The "worst" case is a transaction expiration, the question is more: why the transaction needs to be broadcast multiple time, this defect is consistent like I never seen the deployment of a contract passing first shot. `transaction_validity_period` is set to 100, with 2 blocks per second, this gives 30s. I would expect it never times out on a local net. The retry error is `Retrying request to `broadcast_tx_commit` as it has timed out`. There is in average 1 to 2 retries before it succeed.

Comment: Genesis can be seen here https://github.com/streamingfast/battlefield-near/blob/master/boot/local/genesis.json. If you have other suggestion for tweaking it, I'm all in.

Comment: Hi @Matt, was this resolved ? What did you to fix this ? I am facing similar issue.

Comment: Nope never found the reason